# How to put a big matrix in one column format in IEEEtran.cls?

Tags: matrices

The following is the code for the matrix I want to put in one column in a two column format in IEEEtran.cls.
Any alternative solutions are welcome.

```
\begin{equation}
   \begin{bmatrix}
       V_A \\ 
       V_B \\
       V_C \\
       V_{A^t} \\
       V_{B^t} \\
       V_{C^t} \\
       V_P \\
       V_Q \\
       V_R \\
     \end{bmatrix}   
    = \begin{bmatrix}
                    L_{AA} & M_{AB} & M_{AC} & M{AA^t} & M_{AB^t} & M_{AC^t} & M_{AP} & M_{AQ} & M_{AR} \\
                   M_{BA} & L_{BB} & M_{BC} & M_{BA^t} & M_{BB^t} & M_{BC^t} & M_{BP} & M_{BQ} & M_{BR} \\
                   M_{CA} & L_{C} & M_{CC} & M_{CA^t} & M_{CB^t} & M_{CC^t} & M_{CP} & M_{CQ} & M_{CR} \\
                   M_{A^tA} & L_{A^tB} & M_{A^tC} & M_{A^tA^t} & M_{A^tB^t} & M_{A^tC^t} & M_{A^tP} & M_{A^tQ} & M_{A^tR} \\
                   M_{B^tA} & L_{B^tB} & M_{B^tC} & M_{B^tA^t} & M_{B^tB^t} & M_{B^tC^t} & M_{B^tP} & M_{B^tQ} & M_{B^tR} \\
                   M_{C^tA} & L_{C^tB} & M_{C^tC} & M_{C^tA^t} & M_{C^tB^t} & M_{C^tC^t} & M_{C^tP} & M_{C^tQ} & M_{C^tR} \\
                   M_{PA} & M_{PB} & M_{PC} & M{PA^t} & M_{PB^t} & M_{PC^t} & M_{PP} & M_{PQ} & M_{PR} \\ 
                   M_{QA} & M_{QB} & M_{QC} & M{QA^t} & M_{QB^t} & M_{QC^t} & M_{QP} & M_{QQ} & M_{QR} \\ 
                   M_{RA} & M_{RB} & M_{RC} & M{RA^t} & M_{RB^t} & M_{RC^t} & M_{RP} & M_{RQ} & M_{RR} \\ 
                    \end{bmatrix}
 \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t}
  \begin{bmatrix}
       I_A \\ 
       I_B \\
       I_C \\
       I_{A^t} \\
       I_{B^t} \\
       I_{C^t} \\
       I_P \\
       I_Q \\
       I_R \\
     \end{bmatrix} 
   \end{equation}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of possibilities. The first is to set the big formula in a `figure*` environment on the top of the page. The second one is to split the big matrix across lines like the following.

Such tricks are unfortunately often necessary when two column output is wanted.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{multline}
\begin{bmatrix}
  V_A \\ 
  V_B \\
  V_C \\
  V_{A^t} \\
  V_{B^t} \\
  V_{C^t} \\
  V_P \\
  V_Q \\
  V_R
\end{bmatrix}   
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
  L_{AA}   & M_{AB}   & M_{AC}   & M{AA^t}    & M_{AB^t}   \\
  M_{BA}   & L_{BB}   & M_{BC}   & M_{BA^t}   & M_{BB^t}   \\
  M_{CA}   & L_{C}    & M_{CC}   & M_{CA^t}   & M_{CB^t}   \\
  M_{A^tA} & L_{A^tB} & M_{A^tC} & M_{A^tA^t} & M_{A^tB^t} \\
  M_{B^tA} & L_{B^tB} & M_{B^tC} & M_{B^tA^t} & M_{B^tB^t} \\
  M_{C^tA} & L_{C^tB} & M_{C^tC} & M_{C^tA^t} & M_{C^tB^t} \\
  M_{PA}   & M_{PB}   & M_{PC}   & M{PA^t}    & M_{PB^t}   \\
  M_{QA}   & M_{QB}   & M_{QC}   & M{QA^t}    & M_{QB^t}   \\
  M_{RA}   & M_{RB}   & M_{RC}   & M{RA^t}    & M_{RB^t}   
\end{matrix}
\right.
\\
\left.
\begin{matrix}
  M_{AC^t}   & M_{AP}   & M_{AQ}   & M_{AR} \\
  M_{BC^t}   & M_{BP}   & M_{BQ}   & M_{BR} \\
  M_{CC^t}   & M_{CP}   & M_{CQ}   & M_{CR} \\
  M_{A^tC^t} & M_{A^tP} & M_{A^tQ} & M_{A^tR} \\
  M_{B^tC^t} & M_{B^tP} & M_{B^tQ} & M_{B^tR} \\
  M_{C^tC^t} & M_{C^tP} & M_{C^tQ} & M_{C^tR} \\
  M_{PC^t}   & M_{PP}   & M_{PQ}   & M_{PR} \\ 
  M_{QC^t}   & M_{QP}   & M_{QQ}   & M_{QR} \\ 
  M_{RC^t}   & M_{RP}   & M_{RQ}   & M_{RR}
\end{matrix}
\right]
\frac{\diff}{\diff t}
\begin{bmatrix}
  I_A \\ 
  I_B \\
  I_C \\
  I_{A^t} \\
  I_{B^t} \\
  I_{C^t} \\
  I_P \\
  I_Q \\
  I_R \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{multline}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]